# How can i predict the amount of time it would take for my heron's fountain to stop?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, perpetual-motion

I was assigned a project for my physics class and I'm supposed to build a Heron's fountain and to predict the time it would take to stop so I can then check it experimentally. However, I'm unsure of how can I make the prediction... Please help!

The fountain that I must do is supposed to work for at least 5 minutes according to the guideline given to me.

Comment: In current form, this is question about homework and therefore off-topic. If you just delate the first sentence about you get a relevant question, if you ask me, because its interesting physics  question, follow this https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange guidelines.

Comment: Also, you should describe how the fountain works, and what did you try.